# Object or Array in json

Tags: json

I am trying to get json but am not sure how to read it. Here is the ouput of the json. Is quoteResponse an array or an object? also result is an array or an object? Thanks.

```
{
    "quoteResponse": {
        "result": [{
            "language": "en-US",
            "region": "US",
            "quoteType": "EQUITY",
            "quoteSourceName": "Delayed Quote",
            "sourceInterval": 15,
            "exchangeTimezoneName": "America/New_York",
            "exchangeTimezoneShortName": "EDT",
            "pageViews": {
                "shortTermTrend": "UP",
                "midTermTrend": "UP",
                "longTermTrend": "UP"
            },
            "gmtOffSetMilliseconds": -14400000,
            "marketState": "CLOSED",
            "market": "us_market",
            "priceHint": 2,
            "esgPopulated": false,
            "tradeable": true,
            "triggerable": true,
            "exchange": "NYQ",
            "regularMarketPrice": 47.23,
            "postMarketChangePercent": 0.0,
            "postMarketTime": 1568407854,
            "postMarketPrice": 47.23,
            "postMarketChange": 0.0,
            "regularMarketChangePercent": 0.66070205,
            "exchangeDataDelayedBy": 0,
            "regularMarketTime": 1568404920,
            "regularMarketChange": 0.31000137,
            "regularMarketVolume": 295978,
            "regularMarketPreviousClose": 46.92,
            "fullExchangeName": "NYSE",
            "longName": "Cabot Corporation",
            "shortName": "Cabot Corporation",
            "symbol": "CBT"
        }],
        "error": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *quoteResponse* is an object as

- JSON objects are surrounded by curly braces {}.
- They are written in key/value pairs.

Extract from your original JSON to have it directly in my answer for the purpose of comparison.

```
{
    "quoteResponse": {
        "result": [{
            "language": "en-US"
            "pageViews": {
                "shortTermTrend": "UP"
            }]
        }
}
```

The result is just an array.

A bit offtopic, but maybe interesting:

I landed on a page which describe [Javascript object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) and those are pretty similar to JSON but not the same. JSON derives from Javascript object literal syntax, so the syntax of both are very similar,  one directly noticeable difference is that all names in JSON must be wrapped in double quotes.

JavaScript objects can also contain code (functions) and references to other objects. Their keys can be strings, numbers and symbols. etc.

Comment: There is no thing like a "JSON object" or "JSON array". [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an object or an array but a primitive value can also be represented as JSON). Your answer describes the syntax of literal [JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics).

Comment: That's true :/ Hard to differenciate. JSON syntax is very close to that of object literal. The only difference seems to be that all names in JSON must be wrapped in double quotes and of course the JSON format is language independent. Started with JSON a couple of days ago and was not aware that the curly braces describe objects. Updated my answer.

Comment: There are also other differences. JSON can contain only data, JavaScript objects can also contain code (functions) and references to other objects. Their keys can be strings, numbers and symbols. etc.

Comment: And the most important difference: JSON is text, a JavaScript object is code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an object which is shown by {}.

An array is contained in square brackets [].

You can also have an array of objects [{},{}] - just like the result in your example. You can keep on nesting.

Answer (score 0):

quoteResponse is an object, its value is contained within braces `{...}`.

result is an array, it is contained within brackets `[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

**quoteResponse** is an object. It has properties result and error. In json object has following format {property: value, property2: value}

**result** is an array in json arrays has following format array: [{}, {}...]

Answer (score 0):

quoteResponse is a JSONObject and result  is a JSONArray. A JSONObject can be identified by the enclosing curly braces

```
{"quoteResponse":{"result":[{"language":"en-US","region":"US","symbol":"CBT"}],"error":null}}
```

Whereas a JSONArray can be identified by the enclosing box brackets as in result.

```
"result":[{"language":"en-US","region":"US","regularMarketChange":0.31000137,"regularMarketVolume":295978,"regularMarketPreviousClose":46.92,"fullExchangeName":"NYSE","longName":"Cabot Corporation","shortName":"Cabot Corporation","symbol":"CBT"}]
```